# Using passport and OAuth with connect-redis

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

I am trying to use passport-twitter and passport-facebook for authentication in an app that is using Redis for Express sessions. If I remove the connect-redis for storing sessions in express, everything works fine, but with the Redis sessions, I get the following error:

```
Error: OAuth authentication requires session support
| at Strategy.OAuthStrategy.authenticate
```

My code is below:

```
app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || port);
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser("supersecret"));
app.use('/html', express.static('html'));
app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));
});

if (process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL) {
var rtg = require("url").parse(process.env.REDISCLOUD_URL),
    redis = require('redis'),
    connectRedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express),
    authToken = rtg.auth.split(":")[1];

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(
        express.session(
            {
                secret: 'supersecret',
                cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
                store: new connectRedisStore({
                    host: rtg.hostname,
                    port: rtg.port,
                    db: authToken[0],
                    pass: authToken[1]
                })
            }
        )
    );

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session(
        {
            secret: 'supersecret',
            store: new connectRedisStore({
                host: rtg.hostname,
                port: rtg.port,
                db: authToken[0],
                pass: authToken[1]
            })
        }
    ));
});
}
```

Is it possible to use these together?

**Edit:**
On further debugging, it seems that using connect-redis for the express session store is not setting the req.session to anything. This is what is causing the problem. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make it work at all. Other people with the same issue have fixed it by putting the cookieParser line above the session line, but that's where it's always been in mine, so the issue is something else. I am at a loss.

Comment: I should note that my LocalStrategy works fine with the Redis store; so does Google auth. It is only twitter and facebook that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after two days of searching and poking through the source code of all the node_modules involved (express, connect, connect-redis), I tracked down my problem to a simple stupid typo.

```
authToken = rtg.auth.split(":")[1];
```

The authToken here just provides the password (which is all that redis uses to connect). But to manually choose a database, you need to remove the [1] and pass in the first element as the db name, and the second as the pass. Hope it helps someone else out there!