# Cluster with Passport NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, cluster-computing

In our application, we use a Passport middleware (localStrategy, sessions are stored in a MongoStore). We decided to use Clusters in order to speed up and ease on a server.
The problem is that after this change, passport always is in "not authorized" state.
Is it possible to use passport (localStrategy) with clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport store session data in memory. With Clustering, It is possible for passport to store data in a cluster and other requests handle by other clusters. You must use a session store. I recommend using [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis)

Also these links are helpful:

1-https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/

2-[Using passport and OAuth with connect-redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523991/using-passport-and-oauth-with-connect-redis)

3-https://afshinm.name/2014/06/26/using-redis-as-session-store-for-expressjs-passportjs-settings/

4-https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive

---

**Update**

For MongoDb read these links

1-[Can't store session in MongoDB with passport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633633/cant-store-session-in-mongodb-with-passport)

2-[How can I manage sessions with Passport JS for some routes using express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751855/how-can-i-manage-sessions-with-passport-js-for-some-routes-using-express)

Comment: Thank you, we store passport session data in the MongoStore (MongoDB).Is this option is not good enough for that purpose ?Should I still use connect-redis?

Comment: You mean you write session storing by yourselft?? Yes you can use MongoDb, But bad coding will effect on performance and other aspects! @VictorRodniansky

Comment: I mean ,we are doing:  this.app.use(session({
                                          store: new MongoStore({url:`mongodb://

Comment: Yes, you can use it also

Comment: I mean ,we are doing:  this.app.use(session({
                                          store: new MongoStore({url:`mongodb://
                                          ........
                                          ........
});
We store sessions in mongo..
 this.app.use(this.passport.initialize());
 this.app.use(this.passport.session());
So instead of connect-redis, we use  mongoDb.
Somehow I am always getting a "not authorized" message , even ,when having only one fork.

Comment: Check MongoDb documents and ensure your data save correctly. While reading from MongoDb also check your data and check also keys you use to store and gain data! @VictorRodniansky

Comment: I update my answer, search and read more about using MongoDb! @VictorRodniansky

Comment: Thank you for your help.